# Returning a set of values from JS to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have a function that returns an element's top and left position, like so

```
    $(function GetPos(El) {
      var Offset = $(El).Offset();
      var Top = Offset.Top;
      var Left = Offset.Left;
      return { x: Top, y: Left };
  });
```

I need to be able to assign and store those values using `C#`. I think `Ajax` could be the answer, but I don't know how I would set it up.

I'd like to do something like:

```
    Int Top = someAjax[1];
```

Comment: Here is an example of using AJAX on client side http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp   On the server side you can just receive the parameters with the same names as you've used in the JS

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  It looks like this is designed to take data, processes it and then give it back to the page.  I just need to data without needing a call back.  Can you provide and example?

Comment: i just posted a code example as an answer because I have no idea how to post formatted code in the comments section! Hope this helps

Comment: @BlueLionPiper The HTTP protocol is pretty strict about "Request/Response". There is no "Request/<void>", and Requests can't be initiated by the server. So yes, this should just be an ordinary AJAX; and the server's response doesn't have to contain much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better example using jQuery - this is probably the easiest way to do it.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/DoSomething",
      data: {someParam: "some val"},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
          //If anything needs to done after ajax call happens
      }
    });
```

On the server:

```
public void DoSomething(string someParam)
{
    //Do whatever you need to
}
```